# Add array of data to a List collection

Tags: c#, arraylist

Can someone p'se tell me what am doing wrong?? I am trying to have a list collection that can be dynamically added if for exam a new student registers.

here is my code

```
 classStudent.cs  

public class ClassStudent
{
   public static List<_Student> st = new List<_Student>()
    {

    new _Student { StudentNumber="1234", 
        FirstName ="AAA", 
        LastName = "BBB", 
        UserName = "CCC",
        Password ="DDD", 
        DateOfBirth = "",
        Gender ="",
        EmailAdress = "",
        AwardID =""},

    new _Student { StudentNumber="5678", 
        FirstName ="BBB", 
        LastName = "DDD" , 
        UserName = "FFF",
        Password ="GGG", 
        DateOfBirth = "",
        Gender = "",
        EmailAdress = "",
        AwardID =""});

    }
 }
```

//And then in the same .cs file I write the following method for adding a new student

```
     public static void AddNewStudent(string user_name, string first_name, string      last_name, 
    string gender, string award_id, string date_of_birth, string email_address, string password)
{


    st.Add( new _Student 
    {
        FirstName = first_name,
        LastName = last_name,
        UserName = user_name,
        Gender = gender,
        AwardID = award_id,
        Password = password,
        DateOfBirth = date_of_birth,
        EmailAdress = email_address


    });

}
```

//And now I am calling for the AddNewStudent method in register.cs like below

```
register.cs

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         string first_name = TextBoxFirstName.Text;
            string last_name = TextBoxLastName.Text;
            string date_of_birth = TextBoxDateOfBirth.Text;
            string password = TextBoxPassword.Text;
            string email_address = TextBoxEmail.Text;
            string student_number = result.ToString();
            string _gender = gender.SelectedValue;
            string awardId = AwardList.Text;

    ClassStudent.AddNewStudent(student_number, first_name, last_name, _gender,
                awardId, date_of_birth, email_address, password); //method call
   }
```

But this doesn't seem to do anything, I dont even get any errors but at the same time it doesn't add to the list collection.

Can you p'se advise me on what to change in the above code. All I need is to be able to add to the list if a new student registers.

Thank you

Comment: It seems like you'd have to call it like `ClassStudent.AddNewStudent(...);`

Comment: Sorry, I was my miss-typo, that's exactl how I call it. Just edited my code

Comment: Are you sure you want to call ClassStudent as a static class?

Comment: Could you please advise on why I shouldn't use a static class. I am pretty new to c#. But with the class as it is, I do see to access the elements/members in the class without any problems. Thanks for trying

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample app with your code and can confirm the list gets populated and incremented.

Add a new textbox to your form and after the call to AddNewStudent retrieve the counter for the list:

```
...
ClassStudent.AddNewStudent(student_number, first_name, last_name, _gender,
                    awardId, date_of_birth, email_address, password);

textBoxCount.Text = ClassStudent.st.Count().ToString();
```

You will see with every button click the text box gets incremented.

Comment: I have done what you've said, the textbox shows 4 everytime I click the button but the list doesnt get incremented at all. Thank you though for your help